# Showing that two real matrices are not congruent over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Maybe it is a stupid question but I will still ask it here.

How can I prove that the following matrices are not congruent over $\mathbb{Q}$?

\begin{pmatrix}
  -1 & 0\\
  0 & 2\\
  \end{pmatrix}

\begin{pmatrix}
  -1 & 0\\
  0 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix}

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can read the eigenvalues off any diagonal matrix. can you see how this helps?

Comment: @exitingcorpse actually no. How does it help me ?

Comment: @exitingcorpse I don't see how that helps in this case, since we want to show congruence over $\mathbb{Q}$. All the eigenvalues tell is is whether or not they will be congruent over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @exitingcorpse not sure that is in general so simple see here>> http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92735/when-are-two-diagonal-matrices-congruent

Comment: i misinterpreted "congruence" for "similarity", woops.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fi $B=Q^TAQ$ then $\det(B)=\det(Q^T)\det(A)\det(Q)$, i.e. $\frac{\det(B)}{\det(A)}=\det^2(Q)$ must be a square.

Comment: Thanks!! very elegant answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your matrices are $A$ and $B$ then you should prove whether there exists an invertible matrix $Q$ such that the equation holds:
$$Q^TAQ=B$$

For your and others convenience:

$$\left( \begin{array}{cc} q_{11}^{2}a_{11} + q_{21}^{2}a_{22} &  q_{11}q_{12}a_{11} + q_{21}q_{22}a_{22} \\ q_{11}q_{12}a_{11} + q_{21}q_{22}a_{22} & q_{12}^{2}a_{11} + q_{22}^{2}a_{22}\end{array}\right) = \left( \begin{array}{cc} b_{11} & 0 \\ 0 & b_{22} \end{array}\right).$$

Let $q_{12}=q_{21}=0$ ***for example*** and look for whether/when: $b_{jj} = a_{jj}q_{jj}^{2}$

Saw your comment: general case going deeper see here
[When are two diagonal matrices congruent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92735/when-are-two-diagonal-matrices-congruent)

Comment: Thanks. I know that. but How do u do that. How do u proof that there is no such matrix

Comment: Put your matrices and make the relevant multiplication by keeping elements of $Q$ variable. Your matrices are diagonal and you see from the resulting equation, whether $Q$ existent or not.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Suppose that there is some invertible matrix $P$ such that:

$\begin{pmatrix}
  -1 & 0\\
  0 & 2\\
  \end{pmatrix} 
= P^T 
\begin{pmatrix}
  -1 & 0\\
  0 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix}
P$

Then write out $P$ in component form, i.e. write $P=\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b\\
  c & d\\
  \end{pmatrix}$
(with all entries in $\mathbb{Q}$) and multiply out the right hand side. This will give you some simultaneous equations in terms of $a,b,c$ and $d$. With enough manipulation, you should be able to find a relation between $a$ and $d$ that contradicts them both being in $\mathbb{Q}$.